# Batch ping results to CSV

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, ping

I'm trying to create a script that will let me ping a list of computers from a text file and output whether they respond or not to a CSV file.  When testing the commands using a single machine I receive the correct errorlevel responses, but when I try it using a FOR statement every result is listed as errorlevel 0.

```
for /f %%g in (computers.txt) do (
    ping -n 1 %%g | findstr "TTL"
    if errorlevel equ 0 (
        echo %%g,success >> results.csv
    ) else (
        echo %%g,fail >> results.csv
    )
)
```

What am I doing wrong?  I've tried the code above, as well as that from [Batch ping a list of computer names and write the results to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831218/batch-ping-a-list-of-computer-names-and-write-the-results-to-file) (which doesn't return any responses).  Is there a better way to achieve the result?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Solution**

```
for /f %%g in (computers.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('ping -n 1 %%g ^| findstr /i /c:"try" /c:"out" /c:"TTL"') do (
    if %%a EQU Ping (echo.%%g,Could not find host>>results.csv)
    if %%a EQU Destination (echo.%%g,Destination host unreachable>>results.csv)
    if %%a EQU Request (echo.%%g,Request timed out>>results.csv)
    if %%a EQU Reply (echo.%%g,Replied>>results.csv))
)
```

Updated as noted in the response to G's answer.  Thank you G!

Comment: Are you open to using [tag:powershell] instead?  Much more powerful and flexible than traditional batch files.  Try searching Google for "powershell ping program".  Lots of stuff available.

Comment: I hadn't thought to use powershell for it, but the Test-Connection command looks very useful.  I'll give this a try when I'm back in the office.  Thanks David!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you see if this works for you?

```
for /f %%g in (computers.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('ping -n 1 %%g ^| findstr /i /c:"out" /c:"TTL"') do (
    if %%a EQU Reply (echo.%%g,success>>results.csv) else (echo.%%g,Fail>>results.csv)      
))
```

Sample - 
(I am on home PC and has internet access)

Computers.txt

```
google.com
12.2.2.3
gmail.com
90.2.3.1
yahoo.com
6.6.6.6
10.23.123.24
stackoverflow.com
```

My results.csv

```
google.com,success
12.2.2.3,Fail
gmail.com,success
90.2.3.1,Fail
yahoo.com,success
6.6.6.6,Fail
10.23.123.24,Fail
stackoverflow.com,success
```

Cheers, G

Comment: That worked like a charm, and I see where I made the mistake.  Thanks G!

Comment: Great, glad i could help, but note that this works only for the cases where outputs are "reply from....." and "Request timed out". If you want to consider the outputs like " Ping host could not determine...", "Destination host unteachable" etc cases, you will need to modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Note.  When testing at work I found that systems that had been offline for an extended period (so not listed in DNS) were being skipped on the output.  Adding an additional check in the FINDSTR resolved it.  I updated the question with the full solution.  Thanks again G!

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes and now you can ping, trace and nslookup. sweet!!

```
@echo off & cls

echo Checking connection please wait . . .
echo %date% %time%>> results.csv

for /f %%g in (computers.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('ping -a -n 1 %%g ^| findstr /i /c:"try" /c:"out" /c:"TTL"') do (
    if %%a EQU Ping (echo.%%g,Could not find host>>results.csv)
    if %%a EQU Destination (echo.%%g,Destination host unreachable>>results.csv)
    if %%a EQU Request (echo.%%g,Request timed out>>results.csv)
    if %%a EQU Reply (echo.%%g,On-line>>results.csv))



:tracert
    tracert %%g >>results.csv

:nslookup
    nslookup %%g >>results.csv

    echo ************************************************************************** >> results.csv
)

echo The test is done!
pause

exit
```