# how to extract specific lines from text to another text using batch.

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

Example of my log file with pings on various IP addresses.

```
Pinging 10.62.36.161 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 10.62.36.161:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

================================================= 

Pinging src.g03.yahoodns.net [98.137.236.150] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 98.137.236.150: bytes=32 time=203ms TTL=43
Reply from 98.137.236.150: bytes=32 time=204ms TTL=45
Reply from 98.137.236.150: bytes=32 time=192ms TTL=43
Reply from 98.137.236.150: bytes=32 time=211ms TTL=43

Ping statistics for 98.137.236.150:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 192ms, Maximum = 211ms, Average = 202ms
```

I want to get all the lines with `Request timed out` including the IP address I pinged. Then print out the lines in another file.

Any idea how to get to that?

there is a code I found. the only problem was the results showed 3 extra lines.
code:

```
@echo off
set log=C:\Users\"name"\Desktop\log.txt
set test=C:\Users\"name"\Desktop\test.txt

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set numbers=
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"Request" %log%') do (
set /A before=%%a-1, after=%%a+1
set "numbers=!numbers!!before!: !after!: "
)
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %log% ^| findstr /B "%numbers%"') do  echo %%b) > %test%
pause
```

the results I got:

```
Pinging 10.62.36.161 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
ECHO is off.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=49
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=49
```

anywhere I did wrong?

Comment: Why are you running `%log%` through a `for` loop (you're not, by the way; you're missing the parentheses around `%log%`)? You don't need to do that at all. Just `findstr /C:"Request" %log% >>%test%`

Comment: probably much easier to directly parse the `ping` output instead of a logfile. See for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24965777/2152082)

Comment: @SomethingDark thanks for your reply. I ran the code. it only gave me the lines which contains the word. I need the ip address of the line too. thanks for helping!

Comment: @Mofi thank you for your answer and help. thanks for helping me understand how to process line by line. but I ran the code it gave me only the ip address.

Comment: @ZedekiahTeo My code outputs into the results file only the IP addresses (with or without name) on which `request timed out` occurred at least 3 times. The IP addresses (and names) with a successful reply are not included by design because I thought, according to initial question, being of no interest. It is off course possible to adapt the code to get all IP addresses with status information (replied versus no response) output into the results file. Feel free to adapt the code to your wanted output format.

Answer (score 2):

The approach with **FINDSTR** can't work here as this console application is not designed for finding blocks. It is designed for finding a string in a line and output the line containing the found string.

Here is a commented batch file for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "LogFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\log.txt"
set "ResultsFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\results.txt"

rem Exit this batch file if the log file does not exist.
if not exist "%LogFile%" exit /B

rem Delete the results file if existing for a previous run.
if exist "%ResultsFile%" del /F "%ResultsFile%"

rem Process the log file line by line with assigned the first
rem three space or tab separated strings of each line to the
rem loop variables A, B and C for further investigation.
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3" %%A in ("%LogFile%") do (

    rem Is the first string on the line the word "Pinging"?
    if "%%A" == "Pinging" (
        set "Count=0"
        rem Is the third string "with"?
        if "%%C" == "with" (
            rem The second string is the IP address and no name.
            set "Name="
            set "IP=%%B"
        ) else (
            rem The second string is the name and the third string is the
            rem IP address enclosed in square brackets which are removed.
            set "Name=  %%B"
            set "IP=%%C"
            set "IP=!IP:~1,-1!"
        )
    ) else if "%%A %%B %%C" == "Request timed out." (
        rem This is a line with information that the request timed out.
        rem Increment count and if it reaches 3, then reaching this IP
        rem failed three times and IP and name are written into results file.
        set /A Count+=1
        if !Count! == 3 echo !IP!!Name!>>"%ResultsFile%"
    )
)

endlocal
```

**Note 1:** The whitespace character in `set "Name= %%B"` is best a horizontal tab character and not a sequence of 1 or more space characters as the browser displays according to HTML standard.

**Note 2:** For a valid CSV file as results file with tab character as separator it would be necessary to remove the tab character in `set "Name=   %%B"` and insert it in the line with `echo !IP!!Name!` between `!IP!` and `!Name!`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`