# Ping website and log only lost packets

Tags: batch-file, logging, windows-7, ping

I need help creating .bat file that could only log if packet was lost or some % of it was lost.

Right now I have this script, but it gives to much unnessesecry data.

```
@echo off
:LOOPSTART
echo %time% >> pinglog.txt
ping 50.116.16.98 -n 4 >> pinglog.txt
GOTO LOOPSTART
```

Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

**Log would be left only if Lost is 0<.**

Minimum = 149ms, Maximum = 150ms, Average = 149ms

Comment: See answer on [how to extract specific lines from text to another text using batch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37178087/3074564) to get an idea how to evaluate the results of `ping`.

Comment: But is there a way to make it little bit more simple?
Just output ping result that have only lost packets?

Comment: Yes, it can be done more simple because you want a log file for a single `ping`. So sit down and recode the batch file to your needs. Stack Overflow is in general not a free code writing service. But as your question does not contain any information what should be written into the log file on A) all replies successful, B) no response received at all, C) some replies but also some lost requests, nobody can even start to code the batch file for you. First you need to know by yourself what you want, then code as much as possible by yourself, and last ask for help on a specific remaining issue.

Comment: A very simple filter would be `%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 50.116.16.98 -n 4 | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /C:Packets /C:Minimum >>pinglog.txt` which would write just the lines containing `Packets` and `Minimum` into the log file. Run in a command prompt window `findstr /?` for details on available options of __FINDSTR__.